# Orienting a solid angle

Tags: solid-angle

I'm working on a project in which I need to somehow define oriented solid angle in Cartesian coordinate system, similar to how "regular" oriented angle is defined. And well, I have no idea how to do it. I thought about some plane with one point fixed at $O=(0,0,0)$ but i don't feel if it even is reasonable. So the question is how should I define it and how should I define a negative solid angle with such a definition? I'm looking for some ideas and concepts  to consider because my mind is completly blank at the moment.

Comment: State the vector though the center of the solid angle (assuming it is rotationally symmetric), and the half angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just the vector and half angle?

[image]